# Preventing Multiples

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to figure out how I can prevent multiple of the class asks questions at the same time or the ask2 question currently displaying with the ask question.

[image: http://screencast.com/t/lPURD89wwwEI]

http://pastebin.com/S91NfZVV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at line 26, right after `e.preventDefault();`

---

```
if($('div.question').length){return;}
```

---

This instead will close an existing box before opening another one(has to be placed at the same line)

```
$('div.question').fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
```

Comment: I like that thank you, however after testing it I want to extend it so that if one question is open and the user tries to click on something that has a question on it as well it closes the open one and opens the new choice.

Comment: something looks odd to me. if($('div.question').length){return;}.fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});